# Github pages + Jekyll didn't parse the markdown correctly?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am building a blog site using Github pages + Jekyll, everything seems correct except that the head command #, you can find the display in [hello webpage](http://wangcsshuai.github.io/2016/04/16/hello-2016/), I am sorry that the content is in Chinese, it seems that the head command is not properly parsed.
The github repository is [github](https://github.com/WangcsShuai/WangcsShuai.github.io), I tried to fix it but failed. Thanks a lot.

In markdown, we use

`# Header 1 
 ## Header 2 
 ### Header 3`

which will be parsed as

## Header 1

### Header 2

#### Header 3

to represent different layers of bold fonts, used for section name. in my blog you can see though the header has been bold, symbol # is still there.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I don#t really understand what is wrong with your website, it looks fine to me. What do you mean with `command #`? What do you mean with *"only part of ## is parsed"*?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the unclear description, I have modified the question, the problem for me is that unlike the markdown behaviour here, the symbol never disappear, which is not ' parsed ' as I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not from Jekyll, it's from `anchor-js`, [a script](https://github.com/WangcsShuai/WangcsShuai.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/post.html#L228-L262) that was configured by your theme. I see you can disable it by setting [this line](https://github.com/WangcsShuai/WangcsShuai.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml#L29) to `false`.